# Android: Callback for an application launch

Tags: android, event-handling, android-intent, notifications, termination

Is there a way I can be notified of an application launch and termination in Android? I mean, more like subscribing to the Activity Manager and then determining which applications have been started and stopped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct is to point you towards the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) class, but checking the list of [Intent flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) available to listen for, I'm not seeing anything dealing with application startup/shutdown. I guess the best thing to do is start with this and see if there's some sort of acrobatics you can do that I'm missing in my quick glance.

Comment: But isn't that assuming that the application is actually sending a broadcast of its launch (or to that matter, any of its state) or am I totally off the track?

Comment: Well the system sends broadcasts for certain events too. My hope is that there's some sort of broadcast for app startup/shutdown and I'm just missing it.

Comment: Thank You. I will investigate this matter further.

Comment: did you found any solution regrading? i am also looking for this!